# ffmpeg: edit metadata and automatically increment their name + set the value of "Title" based on "Name"

Tags: powershell, ffmpeg, metadata

This PowerShell code divides a large audio file (`sound1`) in 5 minutes parts and saves them as `sound100_1.mp3`, `sound1_002.mp3`...

```
ffmpeg -i $file_name_complete -f segment -segment_time 300 -c copy $fileNameOnly"_"%03d$fileExtensionOnly
```

- How can I set the metadata `title` to be the same than the `file name`?
- And how can I also (on the same time) edit the `Album` metadata with an incremental name (it's useless, but it's to understand how that work). It should be `alb_1`, `alb_2`.

I have seen [on the docs](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options) that I should use:

```
-metadata title="my title"
```

But:

- <s>should I repeat each time `-metadata` for each metadata?</s> **EDIT:** [yes according to this](https://multimedia.cx/eggs/supplying-ffmpeg-with-metadata/)
- how can I increment the number since the title need to be quoted (`-metadata title="$fileNameOnly""_"%03d` won't work since the last quote is missing)
- how can I set the `title` field so it take the same value than the `Name`?

---

This did not work:

```
ffmpeg -i $file_name_complete -f segment -segment_time 300 
       -metadata title="$fileNameOnly""_"%03d album="test" 
       -c copy $fileNameOnly"_"%03d$fileExtensionOnly
```

I get this error:

> -metadata : The term '-metadata' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Comment: Try `-metadata "title=${fileNameOnly}_%03d"` or ``-metadata "title=`"${fileNameOnly}_%03d`""``. Also, if you want to wrap a commandline across multiple lines you must escape the line break with a backtick.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Thanks (also for the extra tip!). But none of them worked (each title finished with `%03d`, the syntax isn't recognized).

Comment: Did you also change `$fileNameOnly"_"%03d$fileExtensionOnly` to `"${fileNameOnly}_%03d${fileExtensionOnly}"`?

Comment: I just tried, but no. And by the way the last part is working (it only failed when I insert the -metadata on it)

Comment: I think you need to repeat `-metadata` for each metadata value you want to add (`-metadata "title=..." -metadata "album=..."`).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers according to this page, you are right! https://multimedia.cx/eggs/supplying-ffmpeg-with-metadata/